# Ruby - Delay the ruby program till the shell command execution completed

Tags: ruby, loops, zip, delay

I am using shell command to zip file in ruby. Then I am uploading the zipped file to server.
when I use it in a loop like:

```
dump_files.each do |dump_file|
  Open3.popen3("zip #{zip_file}  #{dump_file}")
end
```

And upload, the last file in the dump_files array is not present in the uploaded zipfile but it present in the local file.

I think it happens because of the time delay to zip the file.
How can I delay my ruby execution till the zip command execution complete?

Comment: The problem must be something else. There is nothing to delay, because when you run a shell command with backticks the shell command will not return to Ruby until it *is* complete. Try `sleep 10` and you will see.

Comment: Also it looks suspect that you use double quotes around your command `"zip .."`. You should just run `zip ...`.

Comment: sorry friends, previously I was using Open3.popen3() for executing the shell command. Now it works when I use `` instead of popen3(). thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't that be:

```
`zip "#{zip_file}"  "#{dump_file}"`
```

(in other words, you're not zipping at all?)

Comment: @Sayuj: You are actually trying to call command named "zip zipfile dumpfile", not a `zip` command with arguments. Remove your double quotes. @Denis: He doesn't even need doublequotes around `#{}` as backtick operator already does string interpolation.

Comment: yea. okay.
my problem is the delay in zipping

Comment: @Sayuj - I think you must have some old file laying around, and you're just **thinking** it works, but in reality it's not. Check your commands manually in `irb`.

Comment: sorry friends, previously I was using Open3.popen3() for executing the shell command. Now it works when I use `` instead of popen3().
than you very much guys

Answer (score 0):

Using `` instead of popen3 will fix the issue

replace

```
Open3.popen3("zip #{zip_file}  #{dump_file}")
```

with

```
`zip #{zip_file}  #{dump_file}`
```